# TypeScript TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im getting this compilation error in my Angular 2 app:

> TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

The piece of code causing it is:

```
getApplicationCount(state:string) {
    return this.applicationsByState[state] ? this.applicationsByState[state].length : 0;
  }
```

This however doesn't cause this error:

```
getApplicationCount(state:string) {
    return this.applicationsByState[<any>state] ? this.applicationsByState[<any>state].length : 0;
  }
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. I would like to solve it when defining the attributes the first time. At the moment I'm writing:

```
private applicationsByState: Array<any> = [];
```

But someone mentioned that the problem is trying to use a string type as index in an array and that I should use a map. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Thans for your help!

Comment: If you are trying to define a dictionary (with string keys), use type `{[key: string]: any}`

Comment: Now I'm getting `TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.` when trying to get the number of elements with `this.availableStates.size`.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

If you want a key/value data structure then don't use an array.

You can use a regular object:

```
private applicationsByState: { [key: string]: any[] } = {};

getApplicationCount(state: string) {
    return this.applicationsByState[state] ? this.applicationsByState[state].length : 0;
}
```

Or you can use [a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
private applicationsByState: Map<string, any[]> = new Map<string, any[]>();

getApplicationCount(state: string) {
    return this.applicationsByState.has(state) ? this.applicationsByState.get(state).length : 0;
}
```

Comment: can use a map, React.useState<{[key: string]: string}>({});

Answer (score 128):

Not the OP's direct issue but for users encountering this error for libraries not under their control, one can suppress this error is by adding:

```json
{
  ...
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  ...
}
```

to the `tsconfig.json` file.

---

[Deprecation Notice](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51909) for configurations in TypeScript v5.5.

> These configurations will continue to "work" until TypeScript 5.5, at
> which point they will be removed entirely. In TypeScript 4.9.5+, 5.0,
> 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, and 5.4, you can specify ignoreDeprecations: "5.0" to silence this warning.

Comment: You are missing the point of using a library 'not under your control'. I still stand by my original comment; as the topic subject is the error users will see and search for regardless of the OP's description.

Comment: OP wasn't asking about libraries not under their control, and you didn't mention it in your answer. If you had said "In your case you shouldn't do this, but for other people that have this error in code that isn't under your control then you can suppress the error as follows....", then that would have been fine and got my upvote.

Comment: Option 'suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors' is deprecated and will stop functioning in TypeScript 5.5. Specify compilerOption '"ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"' to silence this error.ts

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Will update with link to GitHub issue.

Answer (score 75):

I used this to get around it so I could use the window object.

```
//in js code somewhere
window.DataManager = "My Data Manager";


//in strict typescript file
let test = (window as { [key: string]: any })["DataManager"] as string;
console.log(test); //output= My Data Manager
```

Comment: Window should never be used  as a workaround. It's the same as using globals. Highly discouraged, bad practice that leads to more long-term issues than it solves.

Comment: see this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71712011/global-window-object-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-index-express

Answer (score 54):

I was actually working with *React* and I got this error when I assigned an object's property through a custom key (i.e. `myObj[myKey] =` ). To resolve it, I simply used **as *keyof***:

```typescript
interface IMyObj { title: string; content: string; }
const myObj: IMyObj = { title: 'Hi', content: 'Hope all is well' };
const myKey: string = 'content';

myObj[myKey as keyof IMyObj] = 'All is great now!';
```

This explicitly tells Typescript that your custom string (*myKey*) belongs to the group of properties from an interface/type you used for declaring your object (*myObj*).

P.S.: another way to get the property's value is shown on a closed [Typescript's issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35859#issuecomment-587290272) through *extends*:

```js
interface IMyObj {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

const myObj: IMyObj = { title: 'Hi', content: 'Hope all is well' };
const myKey: string = 'content';

const getKeyValue = <T extends object, U extends keyof T>(obj: T) => (key: U) =>
  obj[key];
console.log(getKeyValue(myObj)(myKey));
```

Comment: If it worked at one time, it no longer seems to with Typescript 4.7.4

TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof IMyObj'.

Comment: @oravecz [typescriptlang.org/play (code above run in the online compiler)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeB5ARgK2QG9kxgwAbCALmQGcwpQBzAbmQQHtwJxaGmINsgC+AKC4gGyALY4CtDPMIBeYqXJVaAcgASwbQBoO3SH2R7OABxRwKFZMDrIA7hHvbRrCd2lyA0hCY-IwsyGrakmZg2t5icnj4ANoBQchwzgDWQZwwaFiJALrhFgCC9o7OzFAQcGDIIJwuAISxQA) no errors are shown, both in _v4.7.4_ and _v4.8.0-beta_. `console.log(myKey as keyof IMyObj)` outputs "content".

Answer (score 8):

In tsconfig.json

```
 compilerOptions:{

  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "strictNullChecks":false,
  "strictPropertyInitialization": false,

 }
```

Comment: Just changing `tsconfig.json` settings is not a real answer. Perhaps a comment. These settings can be manipulated to do away with any/all TS errors.