# TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```js
const color = {
    red: null,
    green: null,
    blue: null
};

const newColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue'].filter(e => color[e]);
```

The error is in `color[e]` near the bottom with the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ red: null; green: null; blue:
> null; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was
> found on type '{ red: null; green: null; blue: null; }'.

I tried looking everywhere on TypeScript docs, but how am I supposed to `interface` this so it can accept `color[e]`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem you're having is not that `color` is the wrong type, but that TypeScript is inferring the type of `['red', 'green', 'blue']` to be `string[]`.  Often that type of inference is desirable, since (for all the compiler knows) you might want to push `'purple'` onto it.  But in this case, you'd like the compiler to know that the only members are the three string literals `'red'`, `'green'`, and `'blue'`.  That is, you need a type at least as specific as `Array<'red'|'green'|'blue'>`.

Assuming you're using TS3.4 or later, the easiest way to get this kind of type inference from the compiler is to use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions):

```
const constAssertionTest = ["red", "green", "blue"] as const;
// const constAssertionTest: readonly ["red", "green", "blue"];
```

The `as const` causes the compiler to infer a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) composed of exactly the three string literals in the array, in the exact order you've set.  (It's even a [read-only tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#readonly-tuples)).  That is good enough to fix your error:

```
const newColor = (['red', 'green', 'blue'] as const).filter(e => color[e]); // okay
```

All right, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOMC8MDeAoGMkFMATALhjAFd54AaHGAcwPzFIqttwCN5z9XL4WAL4BuLFlCRYk6AEEIEfEigBLcABV80NDADaAIgKF91GPsb5mJs9176AujACGEOOGhiA9J7dTfchSVVDS0oUgInQnB4AE89QyJrcyYwJNt8BzEJd1gwfAB3AGEQRBR0AAoDIySLK1N9dIdnVxkoAEoAOgAzFXgoJXL8NAA+N1LdfHs2sSA)

Answer (score 173):

You can declare `colors` as `any` to tell TypeScript to get off your back on this one (aka *explicit any*):

```
const color : any = {
    red: null,
    green: null,
    blue: null
};
```

But if possible, strong typing is preferable:

```
const color : { [key: string]: any } = {
    red: null,
    green: null,
    blue: null
};
```

More information on indexing in TypeScript: [Index Signatures](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures)

---

*EDIT:* In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358512/1899494) to a similar question, the author suggest using a `Map<,>` -- if that fits your use-case.

Comment: `{ [key: string]: any }`..? TypeScript has you covered with the `Record<string, any>` type.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this and the above comment by @spender is actually spot on. But can anyone actually explain _why_ this resolves the type and using `{ [key:string]: any }` does not suffice?

Comment: @AronRotteveel `Record<string, any>` is be preferable because more readable, but `{ [key:string]: any }` should work as well. Which one you choose is merely a question of style afaict. Did you perhaps give the key a non-literal type, like a type union? In that case, you'd have to write `{ [key in MyTypeUnion]: any }`

Answer (score 18):

I know it is an old question but I'm not satisfied by the other answers. Please avoid the `as` keyword as much as possible !

Let's see why we encounter this error and what to do with it.

### Reason : neither the const nor the array of strings have a type.

When you do not give a type to a const, Typescript infers its type based on the **initial value**. Knowing that, the error just says "hey, `e` could be any string, even strings that are not part of the inferred type of your const". What if `e` was equal to `'yellow'` that is not known in `color` inferred type ?

I can recommend you 3 ways to handle this :

#### 1. Simplest but not so "**Type**script Spirit" solution

Just give a type `string` to the keys of your const, like this :

```
const color: {[key:string]:null} = {
  red: null,
  green: null,
  blue: null
};
```

Hmmm... That works, but we can do better.

#### 2. On the way to types...

Tell Typescript compiler you are using the **keys of** the inferred **type of** the const with the keywords : `keyof typeof`.

In the given example, that would be :

```
const colorKeys: (keyof typeof color)[]  = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

const newColor = colorKeys.filter((e) => color[e]);
```

Can you still make a little extra effort? See next point.

#### 3. Here it is : give types to your objects !

Create an interface (or whatever you need as a type) and give it to your const. Then, specify the type of the array of strings with the `keyof` keyword :

```
interface Color {
  red:number|null;
  green:number|null;
  blue:number|null;
}
const color: Color = {
  red: null,
  green: null,
  blue: null
};

const colorKeys: (keyof Color)[]  = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

const newColor = colorKeys.filter((e) => color[e]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for all the great answers. New to typescript and successfully fixed my first road block.

```
  // in javascript world this is what I used to do.
  let values1 = products.reduce((acc, product) => {
      acc[product] = 1;
  //  ^  --> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.  TS7053

      return acc;
  }, {})

  // in typescript world I needed an extract type specification for 'acc'
  let values2 = products.reduce((acc: { [key: string]: number}, product) => {
      acc[product] = 1; //No more error
      return acc;
  }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `Record`

```
const color: Record<string, null> = {
    red: null,
    green: null,
    blue: null
}
```