# Update an typescript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

When things come to Javascript updating an object is something is like following.

```
const data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 3,
    c: 4
}


const update = (summary) => {
  data[summary] += 1;
  console.log(data);

}

update('a');
```

I tried the same thing with Typescript but it doesn't work as such
I know I'm doing something wrong can someone point out the faults and how to work things out.

```
interface Summary { 
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: number
}

const data: Summary = {
    a: 1,
    b: 3,
    c: 4
}


const updateData = (summaryType: string) => { 
    data[summaryType] += 1 // Error
}
```

The Error is -> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Summary'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Summary'.(7053)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are updating an object with a specific type, TS wants to know that `summaryType` is a *valid* property name (key) for the `data` type.
In this case, you can simply define `summaryType` as a key of Summary, literally:

```
const updateData = (summaryType: keyof Summary) => { 
    data[summaryType] += 1
}
```

In case you have an object literal, and not its type, you can use `typeof obj` to get its type, and again `keyof` to get the valid keys:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

const ObjType = typeof obj;

function update(type: keyof ObjectType) { // or just `keyof typeof obj`
  obj[type] += 1;
}
```

If you don't know the type, or if you want to ignore the error, you can just use `data[summaryType as any]` even if this is not a good practice since you are introducing potential bugs in your code that the TS checker is avoiding.