# How to merge a client-passed config object, with a default config object, in a Typescript class?

Tags: typescript

When writing plain Javascript, i often build classes with a "config" property, whose keys have some default values,  for example:

```
class MyClass{
    config = {
        someProp:true,
        otherProp:5
    }

    constructor(config){
        for(let prop in config){
            this.config[prop] = config[prop] 
        }
    }
}
```

This is very convenient, because i can just loop through the passed object and override defaults(if a value is provided)

In Typescript, i tried something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    config = {
        someProp:true,
        otherProp:5
    }  

    constructor(config?: { someProp?: boolean,otherProp?:number  }) {
        if (config) {
            for (let prop in config) {
                this.config[prop] = config[prop]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ someProp: boolean; otherProp:
> number; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was
> found on type '{ someProp: boolean; otherProp: number; }'.

I understand more or less the meaning of this error, but i guess my whole approach here is very "JS-like", and should be changed.

What would be the conventional, simple way to do this in Typescript? The idea is to quickly merge the provided properties, with the default ones, without repeating various checks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st)

Comment: The problem is type widening in your `for (let prop in config)` -> TypeScript is infering the value of prop as 'string'  and not as `"someProp" | "otherProp"`

Comment: dwjohnston..I don't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: Read the answer in the linked post. FWIW a spread as per the answer here is cleanest solution imo. But it's important to understand type inference and type widening/narrowing  in TypeScript, you're going to run into it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort of do an end-run around the error like this:

```
constructor(config?: { someProp?: boolean,otherProp?:number  }) {
    Object.assign(this.config, config);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsAzASwHNoBedLHOiPAWwFMAFAJzwAcAuAF3YBXZgBpadbHj4ALZuw7ceAVnHQAvtgyr8BCAMHA%20edgAodpMgH4e6aAxYKu16ACM8eEMzAERU2fM4nHgJBRhc5bDUAShoJHAB5FwArZkMAOkgIcgITGRIINPNyEVxCCyiAblU1DDUgA)

That sort of hides the JavaScript-y part behind the `Object.assign` call. :-)

But if you want something with better type checking —this is TypeScript, right? :-) — I'd probably replace the config property and use spread syntax:

```typescript
class MyClass {
    config = {
        someProp:true,
        otherProp:5
    }  

    constructor(config?: { someProp?: boolean,otherProp?:number  }) {
        if (config) {
            this.config = {...this.config, ...config};
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsAzASwHNoBedLHOiPAWwFMAFAJzwAcAuAF3YBXZgBpadbHj4ALZuw7ceAVnHQAvtgyr8BCAMHA+edgAodpMgH4e6aAxYKu16ACM8eEMzAERU2fM4nHgJBRhc5bDUAShoJHBIiaDNCCxjMOLiZEggAOnNyKnQc4qzc-LIRaGK8lPI1AG5VOjVVFpagA)

or perhaps even

```typescript
class MyClass {
    config: {someProp: boolean, otherProp: number};
    constructor(config?: { someProp?: boolean,otherProp?:number  }) {
        this.config = {
            someProp: true,
            otherProp: 5,
            ...config
        };
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsAzASwHMAudCPAWwFMAFAJzwAcqAjPPEesAgBpoeAC4ALesxbsqBAK61OUgL4BuLDnwEIo5vOCi8zABTbSZAPxU00Ggxltr0br35Cxk6aycUFSqWwVAEp0TRwcCRIIADpzcmgAXjCI1Jx7Jh8qPXl6QXC0nE8pRyoAVnzC1Jia+LICiPUClQwWoA)

Spread syntax will do nothing if `config` is `undefined` (or `null`).

You could even use a defined type to avoid writing the same props in two places:

```
interface MyClassConfig {
    someProp: boolean;
    otherProp: number;
}
class MyClass {
    config: MyClassConfig;
    constructor(config?: Partial<MyClassConfig>) {
        this.config = {
            someProp: true,
            otherProp: 5,
            ...config
        };
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCAbOBnPTAexBmAHNkBvAKGXuTyIFsIAFKIgBwC5kAjIkWwQ4IANx0GRMAAtoHbnxABXZv2iSAvjQS4CaLPrzUp9BCTLk+GHPkKWKkhsgsg8YKCoRgiUABRuVgD8fGxwUGDAcNgAPLbGxKQUAHwAlKYuLnLAeAB0QRTIALyZWeVMrIq8yJ4qEAA0ZuXScgqcNQCsTS1Zef2F5M0uWs4MOjpAA)

Answer (score 5):

```
this.config = {...this.config, ...config }
```

seems like it might be what you're after.

You might also choose to declare the type of `config` elsewhere (a type/interface declaration) then use `Partial<T>` as your constructor parameter.

So:

```
interface Config { someProp: boolean; otherProp:number;  }

class MyClass{
    config:Config = {
        someProp:true,
        otherProp:5
    }  

    constructor(config?: Partial<Config>) {
        this.config = {...this.config, ...config }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to first learn the concept of Partial in Typescript :D I'm new to all this.

Comment: @i.brod The `Partial<T>` type is a type that is exacty the same as type `T`, except where all the properties are optional.

Comment: This was the exact thing I was looking for. "Partial" Thanks.