# Typescript when I map imports it says 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' to index type 'typeof import'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

**(parameter) key: string


Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("d:/Projects/Front/attendance-checker2/src/redux/modules/sagas")'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("d:/Projects/Front/attendance-checker2/src/redux/modules/sagas")'.ts(7053)**

I want to use redux saga and separate all my files into modules and then import them to single sagas.ts and reducers.ts. However, if I would like to map imports in order to yield all saga functions Typecript raises the above error.

Here I'm combining reducers and call saga functions `index.ts`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import * as reducers from './reducers'
import * as sagas from './sagas'

export const rootReducer = combineReducers<any>({ ...reducers })


export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(Object.keys(sagas).map((key) => sagas[key]))
}
export default (state: any, action: any) => rootReducer(action.type === 'AUTH_LOGIN' ? undefined : state, action)
```

`sagas.ts`

```
export { default as attendees } from './attendees/sagas'
```

`reducers.ts`

```
export { default as attendees } from './attendees/reducers'
```

Redux folder structure

[image]

`attendees/actions.ts`

```
import types from '../../../constants/action-types'

export const fetchData = () => ({ type: types.GET_PERSON_FACE_IN })
export const setData = (payload: any) => ({ type: types.GET_PERSON_FACE_SET_DATA, payload })
```

`attendees/reducers.ts`

```
import types from '../../../constants/action-types'

const defaultState = {
  data: [],
}

const map = {
  [types.GET_PERSON_FACE_IN]: (state: any, { payload }: any) => ({
    ...state,
    data: payload
  })
}

export default (state: any, action: any) => (map[action.type] && map[action.type](state, action)) || state || defaultState
```

`attendees/sagas.ts`

```
import { takeLatest, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import types from '../../../constants/action-types'
import { setData } from './actions'

function* fetchData() {
  try {
    const res = ['object']
    console.log(res)
    yield put(setData(res))
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

export default function* attendees() {
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_PERSON_FACE_IN, fetchData)
}
```

Unfortunately your suggestion didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st)

Comment: Advice: using `any` all over the place defeats the purpose of using typescript!

Comment: I'm new to using typescript in my projects. However, this will be my first project written in this language). I'm pretty sure that I will use best practices while I'm using this as a primary language)). Thank you for suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(Object.keys(sagas).map((key) => sagas[key]))
}
```

to

```
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(Object.keys(sagas).map((key) => sagas[key as keyof typeof sagas]))
}
```

A short explanation: `Object.keys(obj)` gives you an array of the type `Array<string>`, (`Array<keyof typeof obj>` would not be 100% correct as `obj` could contain runtime keys that your typed code does not know of).
`string` cannot be used to index an object without a string index signature - so you have to manually assert it as `keyof typeof sagas` here.

Comment: Thank you. I found my mistake it was in rootReducer. When I combine reducers which are imported from the other file it says the above error. But now I fixed it in a slightly different way))

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it after reading phry's description to his solution.

```
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(Object.values(sagas).map((key) => key()))
}
```