# errors ts(7053) and ts(2538) in Next.js + Ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

i have googled and found kinda same issues but as i' new to TS i couldn't implement to my case. So

In my `nextjs + ts` app, i enabled internalization for 4 languages.
The content is static and comes from backend.

---

**This is the shape of all of my static content**

```
field: {
 en: "",
 ru: "",
 uz: "",
 oz: ""
}
```

and this is a simplified demonstration of how i'm showing them depending on the site language:

```
const static_content = {
 title:{
  en: "Main title",
  ru: "Основное название",
  uz: "Bosh sahifa",
  oz: "Бош саҳифа"
 }
 ...
}

import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()

static_content.title[router.locale] // Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. ts(2538)
```

i tried:

```
router.locale && static_content.title[router.locale]
```

but in this case it says:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ en: string; ru: string; uz: string; oz: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ en: string; ru: string; uz: string; oz: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

---

---

**Data comes from backend looks like this:**

```
{
 title_en: "",
 title_ru: "",
 title_uz: "",
 title_oz: "",
 ...
}
```

and this is how i'm displaying it

```
interface dataType {
 title_en: string
 title_ru: string
 title_uz: string
 title_oz: string
}

const data: dataType = await fetchData()

data['title_'+router.locale] // error ts(7053)
```

error ts(7053):

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'dataType'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'dataType'.ts(7053)
```

The project was already finished in javascript, i just wanted to convert to typescript. This is the only type error i couldn't solve because i'm new to ts and this only error exists in my 20 pages 2-4 per page so i would like to have simply solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we try and declare an interface for representing `static content` like so...

```
interface StaticContent {
  title: { [key: string]: string };
}
```

and then assign this type to the incoming data like so...

```
const static_content: StaticContent = {
  title: {
    en: "Main title",
    ru: "Основное название",
    uz: "Bosh sahifa",
    oz: "Бош саҳифа"
  }
  // ...
}
```

and then we can easily do

```
router.locale && static_content.title[router.locale]
```

Do we have any problem with this approach in your codebase?

Comment: Yes, this is working for `static content`, thank you. But what can i do for `dynamic content`, most of my content is dynamic? And is it ok to do this `title[router.locale!]` instead of `router.locale && title[router.locale]` as it is less code?

Comment: You can read about [Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). Very useful for accessing dynamic data and very suitable for the cases that you have.

Comment: `{ [key: string]: string }` too is an indexing signature where the type of the key is `string` and the value is also `string`. For complex types, the type of value can be specified accordingly.

Comment: Th only problem is that indexing signature doesn't allow `undefined` value for accessing. To prevent from an error in such cases at runtime, it's better to do a condition check and then try and access.  `router.locale &&` does that condition check, preventing erroneous access at runtime.

Comment: Is the answer good enough for you, or else let me know if you want it adjusted for some specific condition(s).

Comment: i tried this `[title_uz:string]:string ...` idk if it is correct, no error, but i seem to be losing type definition. if i do `data['title_u']` it didn't give error and no autocompletion. would appreciate a real showcase

Comment: You have to specify `index signature` like `{ [key: string]: string }`.  I don't think `[title_uz: string]: string` will be a valid `index signature`.

Comment: Try `const dynamic_data: { [key: string]: string } = await getDynamicData();`. Then we should be able to do `dynamic_data[someStringKey]`..

Comment: Like..... `const data: { [key: string]: string } = await fetchData()`.

Comment: yeah, it was my only choice i did so but i lost type definition... I mean it is not checking for existence. Anyways i am accepting your answer thanks i learnt smth, i'm better learn index signature more

Comment: Depending upon your usage you can use either. So when you have to access based on a key whose value will be known at runtime, use the `index signature` type, and when you want to access with keys from your interface type, use `const dynamic_data: datatype = somedata`.