# Map an array to access dictionary values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, loops, dictionary, foreach

I'm learning, So I have the next code...

```
const numbers = {
 one: "1",
 two: "2",
 three: "3"
}
const arr= ["one","one","two","one","three"]

arr.map((each)=>numbers[each])
```

If I do `numbers["one"]` I get "1", but it is not working with the array, for the previous code I get:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type.

I want to use an array of strings in a dictionary as a keys, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help.

I found the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st) just added to my code `: Record<string, any>`

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(arr.map((each)=>numbers[each]))`?

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me, though. On logging `arr`, I get `['1', '1', '2', '1', '3']`.  Please specify exactly, what problem you are facing.

Comment: I'm using typescript sorry, numbers[each] has two red lines "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type"...

Comment: @kim that's critical information. Can you edit the question please to include it so this question is helpful for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you've noted that you are getting the following error message

> "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type"

Because of the type of your array, `each` is typed as `string`. That means "any possible string value". So it could be "one" or "two", but it could also be "" or "BorisJohnson" or "Fish".

That presents a problem, because you've used that value to index an object literal which ONLY has the keys "one", "two" or "three".

There are two ways to handle this problem, the first is to give your original object literal an [index signature](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-index-signatures/)

```
const numbers: { [key: string]: string} = {
 one: "1",
 two: "2",
 three: "3"
}
const arr = ["one", "one", "two", "one", "three"]

arr.map((each) => numbers[each])
```

However, this is problematic because in the scenario where your array contains values not in the object, the array returned from your map will be typed `string[]`, when in actual fact it should be `(string | undefined)[]` (because `undefined` is what you get when you index an object with a key not actually included in an object).

My preferred solution here would be to provide a more strict type for your array:

```
const numbers = {
 one: "1",
 two: "2",
 three: "3"
}
const arr: (keyof typeof numbers)[] = ["one", "one", "two", "one", "three"]

arr.map((each) => numbers[each])
```

This is a smarter approach because in the event you try to put something into that array that wasn't originally a key of your object, the compiler will throw an error. Because of this compiler error, your `each` variable is now guaranteed to be one of the keys of `numbers`, so will be typed `"one" | "two" | "three"`.

It makes sense therefore that whenever you index `numbers` with one of its keys, you will only ever get a string, and so your array will be typed correctly.

Comment: @Kim no problem. Would you mind marking this is the correct answer by clicking the tick next to the question