# Response.forEach is not a function

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm new in programming especially in Angular and I'd appreciate it if someone help me with my code, please.

I'm trying to get some images from a web API in the angular project.

- ASP.NET Framework Web API 4.7
- Angular CLI: 13.3.7
- Angular: 13.3.11

Web API side:

Controller:

```cs
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    private NavEcommerceDBfirstEntities db = new NavEcommerceDBfirstEntities();
    public HomeModel Get()
    {
        var streetBikes = db.Motorcycles
            .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Street")
            .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
            {
                Image = m.Image
            });
        var sportBikes = db.Motorcycles
            .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Sport")
            .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
            {
                Image = m.Image
            });
        var adventureBikes = db.Motorcycles
            .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Adventure")
            .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
            {
                Image = m.Image
            });
        var scooterBikes = db.Motorcycles
            .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Scooter")
            .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
            {
                Image = m.Image
            });
        var homeModel = new HomeModel
        {
            SportBikes = sportBikes,
            StreetBikes = streetBikes,
            AdventureBikes = adventureBikes,
            ScooterBikes = scooterBikes
        };

        return homeModel;
    }

}
```

Models:

*HomeModel class:*

```cs
public class HomeModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> StreetBikes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> SportBikes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> AdventureBikes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> ScooterBikes { get; set; }

}
```

*Motorcycle class:*

```cs
//Database First Approach and Created by ADO.NET 
public partial class Motorcycle
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Motorcycle()
    {
        this.Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
        this.Dealers = new HashSet<Dealer>();
    }

    public int MotorcycleId { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BrandId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Dealer> Dealers { get; set; }
}
```

*DTO class:*

```cs
public class MotorcycleImgDTO
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

---

Angular side:

Model:

*home-categorised-bikes.model.ts:*

```
export interface FromDTOImgs{
    image: Byte[];
}

export interface HomeModel{
  sportBikes: FromDTOImgs[];
  streetBikes: FromDTOImgs[]; 
  adventureBikes: FromDTOImgs[];
  scooterBikes: FromDTOImgs[];
}
```

Service:

*home-categorised-bikes.service.ts:*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeCategorisedBikesService {

  imageUrl = 'https://localhost:44377/api/Home';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getImg(): Observable<HomeModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<HomeModel[]>(this.imageUrl);
  }
}
```

*app.component.ts:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-UI';

  constructor(private homeCategorisedBikesService: HomeCategorisedBikesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllBikesImgs();
  }

  getAllBikesImgs() {
    this.homeCategorisedBikesService.getImg().subscribe(
      Response => {
        this.onHomeBikesImgsResponse(Response);
        console.log(Response);
      }  
    )
  }

  public bikesImgs: string[] = [];
  private onHomeBikesImgsResponse(Response: HomeModel[]): void {
    Response.forEach((img: HomeModel) => {
      this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.sportBikes}`);
      this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.streetBikes}`);
      this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.adventureBikes}`);
      this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.scooterBikes}`);
    });
  }
}
```

*app.component.html:*

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>

    <div *ngFor="let bikeImg of bikesImgs">
        <img [src]="bikeImg">
    </div>
```

---

Swagger:

[image: Swagger response]

Error:

> Response.forEach is not a function
> at AppComponent.onHomeBikesImgsResponse (app.component.ts)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider working to provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Presumably the actual response from `imgUrl` is not an array, but it's very hard or maybe impossible for anyone other than you to determine that.  If you provide a [mre] then others can help more.  Good luck!

Comment: For debugging reasons it is important to know what value `Response` contains. Presumably, as already noted, it might not actually be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your own swagger screenshot, your response in not an array, it's a list of objects `streetBikes`, `sportBikes`.... Each of those objects are list of arrays.

To loop through each property and to create one single array of all bike images, you need something like this:

```
private onHomeBikesImgsResponse(Response: any): void {
  for (const prop in Response) {
    Response[prop].forEach((item: FromDTOImgs) => {
      this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${item.image}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Nehal, Thank you for your solution indeed. I have copied and pasted your code into my project and the error is gone, however, I am encountering a new error now. (parameter) Response: HomeModel
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'HomeModel'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'HomeModel'.

Comment: Hi @Nehal, I solved the error by editing the Response type to any like this: (Response: any). Now I am getting the images to the browser. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer per your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your API returns `response` with `HomeModel` type, but not `HomeModel` array.

> home-categorised-bikes.service.ts:

```js
export class HomeCategorisedBikesService {

  imageUrl = 'https://localhost:44377/api/Home';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getImg(): Observable<HomeModel> {
    return this.http.get<HomeModel>(this.imageUrl);
  }
}
```

> app.component.ts:

```js
private onHomeBikesImgsResponse(Response: HomeModel): void {
  Response.sportBikes.forEach((img: FromDTOImgs) => {
    this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.image}`);
  });

  Response.streetBikes.forEach((img: FromDTOImgs) => {
    this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.image}`);
  });

  Response.adventureBikes.forEach((img: FromDTOImgs) => {
    this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.image}`);
  });

  Response.scooterBikes.forEach((img: FromDTOImgs) => {
    this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${img.image}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Yong Shun, Thank you for the code indeed. I have modified my project with your suggested code and it is working properly now, however, I would like to use a for loop instead of multiple forEach method. I have also tried Nehal's suggested code, however, I got an error which is: (parameter) Response: HomeModel
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'HomeModel'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'HomeModel'.

Comment: For your new issue, I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57438198/8017690) is what you need.