# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

I have a TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKagMYHsA2qCuAnAzgLABQaAdngC4oar6gC8oA3saKAEoIAmAXKAEScu-ADStQAIXRYEfflJmjxAcRwIEpOavWl+xAL7FiFAJ4AHJABUAwjRwNQAawQnUAM1CmL76pnwBuIyIQUABlVABbJDRMXDxoeCQI1FQueJg8PFRkAEsYCm5QAHcciihPKAQI4jJKX1o8S1QAWRSuBxYiNiE5AAksUgBzBBwlLslpWQFrGHQIvSJDImNzKwAFGBNMGHbGTrYY2j4bOzFFoJCIk1s-aij4txxI0BhQM03trhEX0na1WfQJmoWHQ7QARkgEKVKvYhN8FAhvrRQNoNDVUOQqFcNltUDtjjjPh16jg5Aj+KAlugEFjrnZjjdkYxsR88VwAHSHHCBZbBMAAdSgQOQMFIAHIqJAAFZYOqypClTyoUA5X4IAAeAH4IKQKFhSjlEICKkg1HgQVQcvEoWURqBKDhVYMVR5bU4XKANVaKPFkQMuAg3KrCjkPIquKgEHhxRRvuHI9GJaBSOp2hRlRCVREzOgcrkKMb+KKTAtalQzRana1Ug4uY0Wm0ANpXRk4AC6PJC4DFEWTqEtupGUYK7VVKAyFCdoBbdiV7tcrtWPjrTWrX3tquQSEgGosyCoZXyKqoaBB7VmWVAmf4qN0oAAFEUoHnylaEr9qVwAIQASmIoYfCt0EnIY1x-ZhxFqDAEHZTBBnvfheiHMV4jdZJUi-UQSXrNdmzpPw2x-Hl9E9dA8CQfZqHIaDYNQeD+EsWATxoXBQAjKMYwSRAXmnNp+CIgwgA)

```
// I have colours
const colors = {
  Red: "Red",
  Blue: "Blue",
  Green: "Green"
}

type TColor = keyof typeof colors;

// Some colours have moods associated with them
const colorsToMood = {
  Red: "Hunger",
  Blue: "Calm"
}

type TPayload = {
  color: TColor,
}

// myColor comes from a payload, and really could be either Red, Blue, or Green
const myPayload: TPayload = { color: "Blue" }
let myColor: TColor = myPayload.color;

// Why can't I just use it to index? Intuitively the result is either string if the key exists or undefined if it doesn't, it doesn't need to be implicitly "any"
const resultingMood = colorsToMood[myColor];
// I'm not interested in casting myColor to keyof typeof colorsToMood, since I expect that it could also be "Green" (which is handled!)
if (resultingMood) {
  console.log("Here's the mood!", colorsToMood[myColor]);
} else {
  console.log("That colour doesn't have a mood");
}
```

It doesn't really make sense to me that this example should have an error when the return type is (I think) knowable, even though I'm using something to index an object that doesn't exist as a key.

All the other examples I've seen are contrived or involve casting types in order to solve it, but in this case that would be "lying" about what the type actually is.

What's the preferred way of handling this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript just does not allow indexing of object types with keys that the object type can not have for type safety reasons.

I would give `colorsToMood` an explicit type to solve this problem.

```
const colorsToMood: Partial<Record<TColor, string>> = {
  Red: "Hunger",
  Blue: "Calm"
}
```

This tells TypeScript, that `colorsToMood` can be indexed with any `TColor` member. But the result may be `undefined`.

```
const resultingMood = colorsToMood[myColor];
//    ^? const resultingMood: string | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKagMYHsA2qCuAnAzgLABQaAdngC4oar6gC8oA3saKAEoIAmAXKAEScu-ADStQAIXRYEfflJmjxAcRwIEpOavWl%20xAL7FiFAJ4AHJABUAwjRwNQAawQnUAM1CmL76pnwBuIyIQUABlVABbJDRMXDxoeCQI1FQueJg8PFRkAEsYCm5QAHcciihPKAQI4jJKX1o8S1QAWRTeUAAFGBwKPPQAHk40HC5%20mzsRUEocHNIAcwA%20BYcWIjYhOQAJLHmEHCU1yWlZAWsYdAi9IkMiY3MrLpNMGC4V8RjaPnG-MWugkIiJlsfmoUXibhwkVAMFAZhgT1QL0mMFIrzU53QJmoWHQrwARkgEKVKvYhJMFAhJrRQNoNDVUOQqIDHs92pYWYjXowmPUcHIKfxQDd0AgmUC7F9gdTGMz4ayAHQfHCBW6q%20mM0BqPA43rzVqpBxKxotNoAbUBUpwAF0VSE2KAAHoAfmoGq1Otmc317WmntAAB9QDsuAg3LNuEEgA)

Comment: This is what I would've expected as the default behaviour (without having to set an explicit type to allow indexing with TColor). Thanks for the solution!