# React Icons TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object like this

```
const mockDropdown = [{
  icon: 'MdMonitor',
  label: 'Television',
}];
```

When i use this component i have this warning:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof
> import("/home/user/projectUnknown/node_modules/react-icons/md/index")'.

In this line

```
const mdIcon = MaterialDesign[item.icon];
```

This is the component

```
import { createElement } from 'react';
import * as MaterialDesign from 'react-icons/md';

interface DataIcon {
  icon: string;
  label: string;
}

interface AdvancedProps {
  data: Array<DataIcon>;
}

export default function Advanced({
  data,
}: AdvancedProps) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data && data.map((item) => {
        const mdIcon = MaterialDesign[item.icon];
        return (
          <li>
            <button type="button">{createElement(mdIcon)}</button>
            <p>{item.label}</p>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to load all these icons at once instead of only those that you will use?

Comment: `ìtem.icon` is typed just as `string`, so there is no guarantee that it exists inside the `MaterialDesign` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st)

Comment: searching for the error goes a long way...

Answer (score -1):

You have to add [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ensure TypeScript that this array won't change.

```
const mockDropdown = [{
  icon: 'MdMonitor',
  label: 'Television',
}] as const;
```