# TypeScript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'TestObject '

Tags: angular, typescript

... No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'TestObject '.
I want to iterate through an object in typescript using the following code.
For some reason it works in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmmbbd?file=src/app/app.model.ts) but not in my Angular project in vs code...
I know that there is a similar question if not the same question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st) where they solve it with a new type or type as any.
Since it works in stackblitz but not in vs code i suspect that there might be a problem with my project setting but I don't know where to look for that.

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  myTestObject: TestObject = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 40,
    gender: 'male',
  };
  constructor() {
    this.iterateThroughObject();
  }
  iterateThroughObject(): void {
    Object.keys(this.myTestObject).forEach((property) => {
      console.log(this.myTestObject[property]);
    });
  }
}
```

the type TestObject is in another class

```
export interface TestObject {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
}
```

Is this maybe an issue with my tsconfig.json?

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Strict or typescript version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a `tsconfig` problem. What is happening is that `Object.keys(this.myTestObject)` returns a `string[]`. The way you've defined `TestObject`, it only considers `"id" | "name" | "age" | "gender"` valid properties to index on, not any generic `string`.

In other words, `Object.keys` loses information about the keys of the object it's called on (in this case `myTestObject`). It defaults to the more generic type `string`, which in turn cannot be used to index `myTestObject`.

There are many ways to fix this. The simplest I can think of is to declare a type of `type MyTestObjectKey = "id" | "name" | "age" | "gender"` and then explicitly cast

```
(Object.keys(myTestObject) as MyTestObjectKey[]).forEach((key) => ...)
```

To be slightly safer, you could also explicilty declare

```
const MyTestObjectKeyArray: MyTestObjectKey[] = ["id", "name", "age", "gender"];
MyTestObjectKeyArray.forEach((key) => ...)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The latter option would actually be safe. Typescript can't know if properties have been added to an object, so that's why it uses `string[]` instead of the declares keys. However, if you explicitly iterate over the expected keys, it's guaranteed to be safe. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208