# Global window object: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the error below with `window` declared in our TypeScript file. How can I fix this?

```
const { TestFrame } = window['sisense.embed'];
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

Comment: `Window` doesn't have a known property named `"sisense.embed"`.  What type of property do you expect to see there?  You could merge in a property definition like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weXlEW) but I don't have enough information; could you provide a [mre] where `window['sisense.embed']` actually resolves to something other than `undefined` at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have defined `sisense.embed` on the global `window` object, then you could ignore the error with:

```js
const { TestFrame } = (window as any)['sisense.embed'];
```

See: [**How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709074/1164465)